# ([JavaScript) I cannot access the value with the integer key of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

As the title describes, I cannot access the values of the object below.

```
1: {id: 38, user_id: 3, review_id: 1, created_at: "2020-04-11T04:12:14.569Z", updated_at: "2020-04-11T04:12:14.569Z"}
2: {id: 24, user_id: 3, review_id: 2, created_at: "2020-04-11T03:25:16.589Z", updated_at: "2020-04-11T03:25:16.589Z"}
3: {id: 20, user_id: 3, review_id: 3, created_at: "2020-04-09T12:07:34.669Z", updated_at: "2020-04-09T12:07:34.669Z"}
```

This object is stored in `likes` and keys are in `reviewId`. I confirmed these two variables are stored successfully with the chrome dev tool.
[object check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zu8B.jpg)
[reviewId check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3ELb.jpg)

I tried the following ways to access the values, none of which worked;

```
   if (likes) {
        console.log('reviewId is now ', reviewId);
        console.log('like of this reviewId is now ', likes['1']);
        console.log('like of this reviewId is now ', likes[`${reviewId}`]);
        console.log('like of this reviewId is now ', likes[reviewId]);
        console.log('like of this reviewId is now ', likes[String(reviewId)]);
        console.log('like of this reviewId is now ', likes.reviewId);
    }
```

If my understanding is correct, keys with integer will be converted to string, so I should be able to access the values at least with `likes['1']`. There might be some problem other than how I access, I guess?

Let me know any suggestion if you have.
Thanks.

[Additions]
Please refer to the following codes that might be related to this issue. I am using Redux + Hooks.

```
<./actions/like.js>
import axios from 'axios';
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const setLike = likes => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SET_LIKE,
        likes: likes,
    };
};

export const fetchLike = (likes, userId, reviewId) => {
    return dispatch => {
        const url = `http://localhost:3001/users/${userId}/reviews/${reviewId}/likes/1`;
        axios
            .get(url)
            .then(response => {
                likes[reviewId] = response.data; 
                dispatch(setLike(likes));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
};
```

```
<./reducer/like.js>
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';
import { updateObject } from './utility';

const initialState = {
    likes: {},
};

const setLike = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        likes: action.likes,
    });
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SET_LIKE:
            return setLike(state, action);
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**Demo:**

```js
const likes = {
  1: {
    id: 38,
    user_id: 3,
    review_id: 1,
    created_at: "2020-04-11T04:12:14.569Z",
    updated_at: "2020-04-11T04:12:14.569Z"
  }
};
const reviewId = 1;

console.log('like of this reviewId is now ', likes['1']);
console.log('like of this reviewId is now ', likes[`${reviewId}`]);
console.log('like of this reviewId is now ', likes[reviewId]);
console.log('like of this reviewId is now ', likes[String(reviewId)]);
console.log('like of this reviewId is now ', likes.reviewId);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Comment: Whats your `ObjectName` ?

Comment: what is the name of the variable to which this object is assigned to??

Comment: Running this in my console works for me ```const likes = {
  1: {id: 38, user_id: 3, review_id: 1, created_at: "2020-04-11T04:12:14.569Z", updated_at: "2020-04-11T04:12:14.569Z"},
  2: {id: 24, user_id: 3, review_id: 2, created_at: "2020-04-11T03:25:16.589Z", updated_at: "2020-04-11T03:25:16.589Z"},
  3: {id: 20, user_id: 3, review_id: 3, created_at: "2020-04-09T12:07:34.669Z", updated_at: "2020-04-09T12:07:34.669Z"}
};

const reviewId = 2;

console.log(likes[reviewId]);```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This object is declared below in reducer of Redux; ```const initialState = {
    likes: {},
};```

Comment: I have added a snippet in your code. All of the cases are working fine except `likes.reviewId`

Comment: >palaѕн Thanks! This means there is no problem with how I access the values. This helped me to break down the issue. I appreciate it.

Comment: Where you do all the `console.log` calls, also do `console.log(JSON.stringify(likes))` to see what the value of the object is at moment.

Comment: >  Felix Kling, I did it and that showed the empty object. Now I see the problem. I am using IF statement before where I do console.log, but this doesn't work. Initial state of ```likes``` is an empty object, but not ```null```. Hence console.log() is executed before the content gets stored in the ```likes``` object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be missing a step into drilling to the desired layer of your likes object.
It looks like you've jumped straight from the outer layer, to an inner layer of each numbered object.

Have you tried:

```
likes.1.reviewId
```

Your first attempt (see below) should be returning an object, but won't yet give you the reviewId I understand you're looking for.

```
likes['1']
```

EDIT:

I believe the correct syntax should be:

```
console.log(likes["1"].review_id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. ```likes.1.reviewId``` is an invalid statement in my code though. I will raise another ticket to examine this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I just rebuilt your object in a sandbox and tested this.

likes["1"].review_id

That should work

Answer (score -1):

These are objects. You should define an JS array as

```
arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

and than you can output

```
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I want to access values with keys, but not with sequential numbers. ```reviewId``` happens to be sequential at this point, but this will be random order in the future. That is why I need an associative array.